# execute a native SQL script in JPA/Hibernate - Unexpected token: BEGIN in statement [BEGIN]

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Hello im trying to execute a native query:

```
String script = " Insert into ASSIGNMENT_GROUP (OID,VERSION,DEPARTMENT,NAME) values ('abf7e0e086f311e29e960800200c9a66','0','KS','4441'); ";
```

(The script will contain multiple inserts, but it already fails when i use only one)

Using this method:

```
public void runNativeScript(String script) {
    Query q = oracleMgr.createNativeQuery("BEGIN "+script + "END;");
    q.executeUpdate();
}
```

And get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: BEGIN in statement [BEGIN]
```

If i remove the Begin and End words, the script will execute with no problems, but since i'm gonna do multiple inserts in a single script i need the BEGIN and END.

Could anyone help me, and tell me what's wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could create and execute a separate native query for each insert statement. Is there a specific reason why this is not possible in your situation?

Comment: It is possible and i will use that solution if this fails. It's just that really have a lot of meta-data that i need to insert, and i didn't want to execute 50 native queries if i could get away with just firing off one script.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```java
public void runNativeScript(String script) {
    Query q = oracleMgr.createNativeQuery("{ call BEGIN " + script + " END }");
    q.executeUpdate();
}
```

This is standard SQL92 syntax. You can see examples in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/getsta.htm#JJDBC28075.

Comment: TY for the answer, i got rid of the first error, but now i get a new one: 
java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: INSERT in statement [  call BEGIN  Insert into ASSIGNMENT_GROUP (OID,VERSION,DEPARTMENT,NAME) values ('abf7e0e086f311e29e960800200c9a66','0','KS','4441'); END  ;]

Comment: Can you provide more information? For example: which Oracle driver are you using? How did you set up your persistence unit? Can you provide a full stacktrace? Can you provide a minimal complete test program that reproduces the problem?